# Printing only once in a for loop

Tags: python, python-3.x, for-loop

Hello I'm trying to print out the items shown below.I only want them printed once but since the print statements are inside the for loop, they are being printed 100 times. and I can't take the print statements out because the values inside are dependent on the for loop. Any ideas on how to print those values only once?

```
def Input_Q_bounds (lower,upper):
delta_x = .1

#since there are 100 iterations
J=np.zeros(101)
for i in range(101) :
    Q_i=(i*delta_x)+(delta_x/2)
    if lower <=Q_i<= upper :
        Q =1
    else :
        Q=0
    #now fill the matrix
    J[i]=(Q+(9.5*(J[i-1])))/10.5
    J_analytical = Q*(np.exp(upper-10)+(np.exp(lower-10))

    print(J_analytical)
    print(J[100])
```

Comment: How are the values dependant on the for loop? If you're getting your expected output for the first print, then you don't need a loop at all. Just i=0

Comment: You may add an if-else conditiion with print statement

Comment: Do you only want to print the final value at the end of the loop? If so then you can take them out.

Comment: Please post a full example of code that produces the problem; this allows us to better understand the context, and to test a solution.

Comment: This isn't entirely clear.  First of all, your loop has 101 iterations, not 100: all the values for 0 through 100.  Second, you *can* remove the **print** statements, as variable values are properties of the function, not the loop scope.  Third, your code can't run, as the indentation is faulty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just put an `if i == 100:` in the line above the printing

Comment: great idea! I have tried this though and it gives me this syntax error do you know why?                   
    File "<ipython-input-158-4dfe97d189b5>", line 18
    if i==100:
             ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: I can't fathom why this answer is chosen over printing outside the loop when it ends. There should be no need to continuously check _"am I at the end of the loop"_

Answer (score 1):

Option 1: You can use an else condition like below.

```
def Input_Q_bounds(lower, upper):
    delta_x = .1

    # since there are 100 iterations
    J = np.zeros(101)
    for i in range(101):
        Q_i = (i * delta_x) + (delta_x / 2)
        if lower <= Q_i <= upper:
            Q = 1
        else:
            Q = 0
        # now fill the matrix
        J[i] = (Q + (9.5 * (J[i - 1]))) / 10.5
        J_analytical = Q * (np.exp(upper - 10) + (np.exp(lower - 10))
    else:
        print(J_analytical)
        print(J[100])

if __name__ == "__main__":
    Input_Q_bounds(lower, upper)
```

Option 2: The below solution is by using global variables

```
J_analytical = -1
J = []

def Input_Q_bounds(lower, upper):
    global J
    global J_analytical
    delta_x = .1

    # since there are 100 iterations
    J = np.zeros(101)
    for i in range(101):
        Q_i = (i * delta_x) + (delta_x / 2)
        if lower <= Q_i <= upper:
            Q = 1
        else:
            Q = 0
        # now fill the matrix
        J[i] = (Q + (9.5 * (J[i - 1]))) / 10.5
        J_analytical = Q * (np.exp(upper - 10) + (np.exp(lower - 10))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    Input_Q_bounds(lower, upper)
    print(J[100])
    print(J_analytical)
```

Option 3: Return the values from the function.

```
def Input_Q_bounds(lower, upper):
    delta_x = .1

    # since there are 100 iterations
    J = np.zeros(101)
    for i in range(101):
        Q_i = (i * delta_x) + (delta_x / 2)
        if lower <= Q_i <= upper:
            Q = 1
        else:
            Q = 0
        # now fill the matrix
        J[i] = (Q + (9.5 * (J[i - 1]))) / 10.5
        J_analytical = Q * (np.exp(upper - 10) + (np.exp(lower - 10))
    return J[100], J_analytical

if __name__ == "__main__":
    Input_Q_bounds(lower, upper)
```

Comment: A global variable as a return technique is a generally bad practice.

Comment: @Prune That is true. I believe this can be edited to return the values.